# How does alias-parent-active get implemented?

Tags: menu, alias, active

I have 2 menus - one main menu and effectively an alias menu.

**Main Menu**

About

Products

- Prod 1
- Prod 2 etc

**Alias Menu**

- Alias pointing to Prod 1
- Alias pointing to Prod 2

There is no 'parent' item for the alias menu. I would have expected when I click on an item in the Main Menu for the active-alias to get triggered as well? Is this not default behaviour or do I need a parent alias in my alias menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario you are describing, the Alias Menu Items usually become `active`, following their original menu item state.

The menu module applies the `active` class to that item, and with the appropriate css from your template, it would get the extra styling, to denote visually that it is active.

Check with the developer's tools in your browser, to see the output of your second menu.

It can be that there is a module override for the menu module in your template, or that your template does not have any special styling for this scenario at the module position of your menu, or another css override may affect the desired styling.